# Custom Plugin for add fee in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

my code working fine in functions file

how i can create a custom plugin for working this code ?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'wpdesk_checkout_fee' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'wpdesk_checkout_fee' );
function wpdesk_checkout_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $list = array();
    foreach($items as $item=> $values ){
        array_push($list, $values['product_id']);   
    }
    foreach($list as $productid){
        if($productid == 2361){
            $fee = (int)-5000;
            WC()->cart->add_fee( "fee: ", $fee, false, '' );

        }
    }

}
```

i need correct snippets for use in custom plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert your working code into a plugin.

**Step1:** Create a folder for your plugin name (Example: custom-plugin)

**Step2:** Create a new file with the same name as your plugin

**Step3:** Add your code to this file

**Step4:** Make sure you have added the headers for the plugin file.

Finally, your plugin code will be like this.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Customize Other Plugin Output
Plugin URI: http://brianhogg.com/
Description: Changes the output from The Other Plugin using a bit of code
Author: Brian Hogg
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://brianhogg.com


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'wpdesk_checkout_fee' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'wpdesk_checkout_fee' );
function wpdesk_checkout_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $list = array();
    foreach($items as $item=> $values ){
        array_push($list, $values['product_id']);   
    }
    foreach($list as $productid){
        if($productid == 2361){
            $fee = (int)-5000;
            WC()->cart->add_fee( "fee: ", $fee, false, '' );

        }
    }

}
```

Refer to this link for more details https://brianhogg.com/functional-wordpress-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder of your plugin name (Dont use space)
2. Create file with the same name of plugin (Dont use space)
3. Add code to your plugin file using below details for plugin

[image]